# Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, struts2, persistence

I'm working to create an java web apps using Struts and a Cassandra DB. This post is not unique to my configuration because persistence.xml is using by many API/ORM.

So, I already build 1 project where I just insert/delete/update/read in my database. For this project i needed persistence.xml and all running nice.

But now, I joined 2 project and I create an build.xml for creating my project in tomcat 6.
I put /META-INF/persistence.xml in this folders :
WEB-INF
WEB-INF/ressources
/

Thanks for help and sorry for my broken english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

Put it in WEB-INF/classes, not WEB-INF/ressources

Comment: Sean Patrick Floyd , YOU ROCKS ! Thanks a lot !! I dont have any influence point for vote but thanks !